# Lua Tables: how to assign value not address?

Tags: memory, lua, lua-table, luajit

Here is my code:

```
test_tab1={}
test_tab2={}
actual={}
actual.nest={}

actual.nest.a=10
test_tab1=actual.nest 
print("test_tab1.a:" .. test_tab1.a) -- prints test_tab1.a equal to 10

actual.nest.a=20
test_tab2=actual.nest 
print("test_tab2.a:" .. test_tab2.a) -- prints test_tab2.a equal to 20
print("test_tab1.a:" .. test_tab1.a) -- prints test_tab1.a equal to 20
```

Actual Output:

```
test_tab1.a:10
test_tab2.a:20
test_tab1.a:20
```

As per my understanding both `test_tab1` and `test_tab2` are pointing to same address i.e actual.nest so when I am assigning **`actual.nest.a=20`** value of **`test_tab1.a`** is also changing to 20 which was 10 previosuly.

Expected Output:

```
test_tab1.a:10
test_tab2.a:20
test_tab1.a:10
```

Can anyone help me getting this output?.If i am changing `actual.nest.a=20` second time it should not reflect in `test_tab1.a` i.e 10

Comment: Output is correct

Comment: Output is correct that is okay. But how can u i get second output?

        test_tab1.a:10
        test_tab2.a:20
        test_tab1.a:10

Comment: You need create separeate table. You can do this when assign to `test_tab1` or when assign `test_tab2` and change value in this copy. It really depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do a copy/clone of the tables from `source` to `destination`. Doing `t1 = t2` just assigns `t1` the address of `t2` to `t1`.

Here's a copy of [shallow copy method](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) you can use:

```
function shallowcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
            copy[orig_key] = orig_value
        end
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end
```

---

```
actual={}
actual.nest={}

actual.nest.a=10
test_tab1 = shallowcopy(actual.nest)
print("test_tab1.a:" .. test_tab1.a) -- prints test_tab1.a equal to 10

actual.nest.a = 20
test_tab2 = shallowcopy(actual.nest)
print("test_tab2.a:" .. test_tab2.a) -- prints test_tab2.a equal to 20
print("test_tab1.a:" .. test_tab1.a) -- prints test_tab1.a equal to 20
```